# Shell script doesn't work when run from startup applications

Tags: scripts, touchpad, startup-applications

I have created a script to modify my touchpad settings, based on the [instructions in this Tech Republic article: Tweak your touchpad to taste in Linux](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tweak-your-touchpad-to-taste-in-linux/)

I've done the following:

```
synclient -l > touchsettings
```

to create a file named 'touchsettings' containing all my touchpad's settings.

Then I used `gedit` to edit the settings as I want them, as well as adding a hash bang to the start of the script. I ran

```
chmod u+x touchsettings
```

to give the file execute permission.

The script does what it's supposed to if I then run `./touchsettings`

But when I add the script to startup using the Startup Applications GUI (Add > Browse, then browse to file location of touchsettings), then restart the computer, touchpad functionality stops working entirely.

Why does this script work fine when calling `./touchsettings`, whereas it breaks the touchpad when called at startup?

Comment: Add the *full path* to the script to startup applications, + the break, as described in the dupe link.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what you mean by 'add full path to the script' though - how would I do this? When I look at the `touchsettings.desktop` at `~/.config/autostart` it looks like below. The delay works - it now takes 60sec after loading for the touchpad to stop working :( 
    `[Desktop Entry]
    Type=Application
    Exec=/home/jemily/touchsettings
    Hidden=false
    NoDisplay=false
    X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
    Name[en_NZ]=touchpadSettings
    Name=touchpadSettings
    Comment[en_NZ]=
    Comment=
    X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=60`